# impossible to pass user's input to the array

Tags: java

I am trying to pass user's input to the array through a scanner. The goal is to make the average value of the inputs, this is the code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            double[] str1 = new int [20] ;
            str1 = scanner.next.Double();
            System.out.println("Average is: " + Arrays.stream(str1).summaryStatistics().getAverage());
        }

}
```

Comment: One last thing, as hint in the program it gives me that I may change the value of str1 to int (making it not a array)

Comment: `double[] str1 = new int [20] ;` ????

Comment: Maybe you mean `scanner.nextDouble()` - please at least start with code that will compile.

Comment: What @Scary Wombat meant, you need to create a double[] if you save it to a double[][] variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below 2 statements are having syntax error and because of this code will not compile:

```
double[] str1 = new int [20] ;
str1 = scanner.next.Double();
```

you need to declare double array as `double[] str1 = new double[20];`

you need to take the double value as input like this `scanner.nextDouble();` and as str1 is array we can't store the input directly as `str1 = scanner.nextDouble();` in that case your program will give compile time error

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to double[]

To resolve this error we need to store the value of every input at specific index like `str1[0] = scanner.nextDouble();`

Below is the working code as per your requirement(as I understand from your question):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

double[] str1 = new double[20] ;

for(int i = 0; i < 20;i++) {
   str1[i] = scanner.nextDouble();          
}
System.out.println("Average is: " + Arrays.stream(str1).summaryStatistics().getAverage());
```

I hope it will help you resolve the error you're facing.